# pyplot colorbar properties (gap and tick labels) not responding

Tags: matplotlib, scaling, subplot, colorbar

Colorbar tick properties fail and subplot axis scaling fail to respond to explicit instructions for a 2x2 multiplot.

For example, the code for following graphic specifies a colorbar gap=0.0, yet there is still a space. When I specify a negative gap value for subplot 1, it disappears [8-Apr: no longer having this issue, but now entire subplots shift horizontally with negative cbar gaps values....not implemented in code sample below, though].

Similarly, colorbar tick labels are unresponsive. I have tried:

```
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(fontname='Arial', fontsize=somevariable)
```

and

```
cbarticklabs = cbar.ax.get_yticklbels()
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(cbarticklabs, fontsize=somevariable)
```

and

```
for font_objects in cbar.ax.yaxis.get_ticklabels():
    font_objects.set_size(somevariable)
```

I've tried a couple of other code configurations, but all seem to produce the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ax'
```

EDIT 7-Apr: My code follows with random data in the interest of being "complete" and "verifiable". Subplot size is now changing (and ignoring ax.set_lim and ax.set_ylim commands) with data extent governing (ax.set_xbounds and ax.set_ybounds are ignored as well, but not included here).

EDIT 8-Apr: Stripped-out bits that seem irrelevant (e.g. axis labels, background image, etc). Got for loop working, but now cbar label not consistently centered. Seem to have gained control over subplot extents and erroneous cbar gap has gone away. Still no control over cbar tick properties and now can't get X and Y axes to scale the same.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Global variables, lists, and dicts

spextents = [1800000, 1830000, 5444000, 5485000] # desired [xmin, xmaz, ymin, ymax] for subplot
extbuf = 1000
cbarlab = 'meters of horizontal error'
cbarlabelpadval = -28
ticklabsize = 8
figszx = 9
figszy = 12
ptscalefact = .2
SplocYrKeyDict = {1:'194', 2:'196', 3:'198', 4:'2017'}
YrCompDict = {'194':'1941-1944', '196':'1961-1966', '198':'1989', '2012':'2012-2013', '2017':'2017'}
MaxErrDict = {1:50, 2:60, 3:250, 4:2}

# Create a figure with 2x2 subplot 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(figszx, figszy), dpi=120, sharex=True, sharey=True) # sharex and sharey ignored when plotting, 
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace = .1, wspace = .1)


for sploc, yr in SplocYrKeyDict.items() :
    ax = "ax" + str(sploc)
    ax = plt.subplot(2,2,sploc)
    compyr = SplocYrKeyDict[sploc]
    ToX = np.random.randint((spextents[0]+extbuf),(spextents[1]-extbuf), size=(80,1))
    ToY = np.random.randint((spextents[2]+extbuf),(spextents[3]-extbuf), size=(80,1))
    DistScale = np.random.randint(0, MaxErrDict[sploc], size=(80,1))
    p ="p" + str(sploc)
    p = ax.scatter(ToX, ToY, c=DistScale, zorder=9, s=DistScale*(figszx*ptscalefact), cmap='autumn_r') # (X, Y, color, drawing order, point size, colormap..."_r" extention flips the coloramp)
    plt.axis(spextents, aspect=1) #neither 'scaled', nor aspect=1 work cause axes to plot same when X != Y image dimensions
    ax.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=ticklabsize)
    cbar = fig.colorbar(p, ax=ax, orientation='vertical', aspect=30, pad=0.0).set_label(cbarlab, labelpad=cbarlabelpadval, fontname='Arial', fontsize=ticklabsize)
    #cbarticklabs = cbar.ax.get_yticklbels()
    #cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(cbarticklabs, fontsize=ticklabsize)
    #cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(fontname='Arial', fontsize=ticklabsize) #....won't run

# draw to plot
plt.show()
```

This produces:
[getting closer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DQU9.png)

Ultimately, I'm trying to get to something like:
[nearly there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvfSe.png)

but with the colorbars immediately adjacent to each subplot (or, ideally superimposed on each subplot). And colorbar tick label text the same size as the X and Y axis ticks (and, ideally, superimposed on the colorbar itself)

Given that the subplots seem to also be ignoring the x and y bounds and sharex / sharey arguments, I'm thinking my problem may be at a fairly high level in the code? Unfortunately, I'm a geoscientist, not a codewriter and the amount of time I have invested in this exercise while exceedingly educational, has been exorbitantly time-consuming. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Users of matplotlib are almost never codewriters *per se*; they are scientists like you who need to write code. Being a scientist, you should be very open to the concept of reproducibility. Here this would translate into providing a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: Thank-you for the response. Given the full code is 185 lines long and the problem is not specific to a subplot position, I truncated to a single subplot plus relevant higher-level code. Also trimmed variable defs as they don't seem pertinent. I had thought I'd found the balance you note rather well. Your comment indicates I haven't and I apologize for that. Is it not minimal enough? Not complete enough? I didn't include a data sample as it doesn't appear to be relevant (the code & data run fine outside of a subplot environment).  Please advise. Cheers

Comment: Creating 4 subplots costs ~8 to 10 lines of code, plus 4 colorbars and some adjustments give you maybe 20 lines. So there is definitely something too much in the code. The main point about [mcve] is however that it should be runnable and understandable. Someone reading the question should be able to copy the code and run it. Hence don't use `ToX = PtsAzDist.ToX[PtsAzDist.PhotoYear...` but rather `a = [1,2,3,..]` or whatever is needed here.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. Edits made to original post. Thank-you also for reassuring that it is possible to achieve with fewer lines of code.  As other users will hopefully understand, at some point "should" needs to be triaged for "is". In my case, that was after about 15-20 hours of unsuccessful efforts with for, for-where, and nested-for loops.  Only so much time can be allocated to such things. As a novice Python user, I'm still very much at the point of holding my breath each time I hit the 'run' button.  Thank-you for any suggestions.